# Words for ordinal 5-point scale from normal to severe

Tags: science, publishing

What are good words for a five-point ordinal scale? The scale should represent increasing severity of disease, where 1 is normal and 5 is severe.

I thought of the following words (with their value in words in parentheses):

1. normal (= no disease)
2. mild (= low disease presence)
3. moderate (= between normal and severe)
4. moderately severe (= not the worst case, nor in the middle)
5. severe (= worst form of disease)

I'm not happy with moderately severe, though, and I can't find a good alternative. Also, I'm not fond of moderate, because it somewhat has the same value as mild. Another word that might be used in the scale is slight, which would be second to normal. I'd like to know if there are other words (especially single words, not multiple) that appreciate the values I'm trying to give the scale.

Because I'm not a native English speaker, I want to know if you feel like the option I present here are reasonable and if not what words you feel are better.

This is similar to a [Likert scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likert_scale) which is used a lot for questionnaires. The words it often uses are: strongly disagree, disagree, neither agree nor disagree, agree, strongly agree.

Comment: Perhaps you can use severe, instead of moderately severe, and extremely severe or critical instead of severe?

Comment: Ok, but then I'd get (e.g.): normal-slight-moderate-severe-extreme. I feel there's too much of a gap between moderate and severe. Do you feel the same?

Comment: I think this is going to end up just being opinion.

Comment: As often with language. I'm not a native speaker, so I want to know how others feel about the options I present and if you feel there are better ones. That is subjective in the first place.

Comment: In my opinion, it is fine. Also, if you make a quick Google search about "mild, moderate and severe", you will find many examples of them used to describe different degrees of severity when talking about diseases. I would say that, by adding "normal" and "extreme", you are just adding two additional levels, one at each end of the scale. What do you think?

Comment: Also, I have found this [scale of severity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injury_Severity_Score), maybe you can use something like that...

Comment: Are there not standards for this, supplied by bodies like the BMA (British Medical Association) or its equivalents elsewhere? Try their website.

Comment: Not for the specific properties I'm investigating. The problem is there are many scales, but I can't seem to find one from normal to diseased. I like the idea of adding normal and extreme around slight, moderate and severe.

Comment: On American TV commercials advertising pharmaceuticals, one often encounters the adjectival phrase "moderate-to-severe". Not necessarily recommending this, but it is something to bear in mind.

Comment: It's worth noting that in medicine the terms "Acute" and "Chronic" are often used.  Maybe variations around those?

Comment: Did you find anything from a goodgle search? If so, what similar scales did you see and why weren't they sufficient?

Comment: @Majenko: as far as I know, *acute* and *chronic* refer to persistence/duration rather than severity, so I am not sure wether they would apply in this case

Comment: @SamualVimes Formally, Yes, but informally it also refers to the severity.

Comment: You could always base it on the *Beaufort Wind Scale* which goes from Force 1 - Calm to Force 12 - Hurricane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you can use something like this:

> 1) Normal
>   2) Minor
>   3) Moderate
>   4) Serious
>   5) Severe

In a similar way to the [Abbreviated Injury Scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbreviated_Injury_Scale)

Comment: Good idea to point to the AIS!

Comment: A possible substitute for "serious":  *advanced*

Comment: I like your answer and I accept it. I've chosen normal, slight, moderate, severe, extreme. But I will discuss this your scale with my peers.